# How to make bootstrap 4 numeric keypad template auto submit after 4 characters

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I always struggle with this. I wish I could use more than one id="" per element.  But I know I can't.  As I struggle with JavaScript and Ajax, but I try. I use JavaScript to capture the #code id for the user sign in number, and Ajax to count inputted characters.  How can I trigger the Ajax to execute Upon the forth character being inputted.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div style="float:left;width:60%;background:lime1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                <div  class="btn-group-vertical ml-4  mt-4 " role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <form id="form" action="barista_punch_menu.php" action="post">
                            <input type="text" autofocus style="font-size:40px" class="text-center form-control-lg mb-2" id="code" id="sID"  value="" name="barista_id" placeholder="Enter Barista Id:" maxlength="4" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 " onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '1';">1</button>
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 " onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '2';">2</button>
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 " onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '3';">3</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 " onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '4';">4</button>
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 " onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '5';">5</button>
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 " onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '6';">6</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 " onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '7';">7</button>
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 " onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '8';">8</button>
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 " onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '9';">9</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 2" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value.slice(0, -1);">Del</button>
                        <button type="button" class="num btn btn-outline-secondary py-3 3" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value=document.getElementById('code').value + '0';"> 0 </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="num btn btn-primary py-3 4" onclick="">Go</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$('button.num').click(function() {
  if($('#code').val().length >= 4)
    $('#form').submit();
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the **Bootstrap Numpad Example**, Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're listening for the wrong event.

> The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard.

But your input is being processed from the numeric keypad you did with buttons.

You can bind it to the actual button clicks by adding a class to your numeric buttons:

```
<button class="num" ...>0</button>
```

And then adding the event handler:

```
$('button.num').click(function() {
  if($('#code').val().length >= 4)
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Sorry to say that did not work.  I edited my question with the changes you suggested.  Are we missing something else?  I see what your are doing here, it does make sence

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hLer2yfm/ Works in this fiddle. Check your console. Are you getting anything?

Comment: You of course are right.  I copied and pasted the jsfiddle code to my server and it WORKED.  I have some other stuff going on on my real page, probably a conflict.  I will figure it out.  Thanks for your help.